# Kurinji Andavar Temple

Tags: kartikeya

I had visited 'Kurinji Andavar' Temple situated at 'Kodaikkanal' earlier & am curious about it.
On searching, found that as per the Tamil literature, Kurinji means 'hill region' and Andavar means 'God', hence Lord Muruga is referred as 'God of hill'.
(Murugan means Kartikeya).
Now the question --
What is the reason behind choosing Kartikeya as God of hill?

Comment: Aandavar literally means ruler. I think the title does not belong to all hills but to that particular hill. For example, Srinivasa is known to be the ruler of the hills in Tirupati, but his epithet will be 'ruler of the hill'. Usually in the epithets they do not say the hill's name but there are exceptions.

Comment: I got your point. But my question is a little different. As regarding Lord Srinivasa at Tirupati, there is a story why he is the God over there. In the same way, what is the story behind Lord Kartikeya being the God over Kodaikkanal Hills?